# ASP.NET Web API action routing doesn't not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm new to Web API, I know one of the difference between web api and MVC
is that web API uses HTTP method to choose which method to invoke by convention.

> Now I added an action parameter into my route,
>   I think there's something went wrong to my knowledge,
>   the route doesn't work.

Here's my controller, main problem is that I just need to map the **SignIn** and **SignUp** method.
(Other RestFul methods work fine.)

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private Model1Container db = new Model1Container();

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.UserSet;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SignIn(string account, string password)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SignUp(User user)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id, User user)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

What I've tried is even to add the direct constraint on my top two routes for both methods,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UsersSignIn",
            routeTemplate: "api/Users/SignIn",
            defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "SignIn" }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UsersSignUp",
            routeTemplate: "api/Users/SignUp",
            defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "SignUp" }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RestFulUser",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Users" }
        );
```

But it turns out [POST] **"api/Users/SignUp"** and **"api/Users"**
could map to SignUp method, but **"api/Users/SignIn"** always not succeed.

And here's about how I try the API in POSTMAN

[image: POST MAN]

Please point out where did I go wrong ..

Comment: Did you call `config.Routes.MapAttributeRoutes`?

Comment: Yes, so that other RestFul methods work fine.

Comment: Decorate the your methods like `[HttpPost][Route("SignIn")]` where they deviate from the conventions and remove all but the last call to `MapHttpRoute`

Comment: Then "api/Users/SignIn" always maps to SignUp method..if I remove SignUp method then it returns a message "The resource you request does not support Http Post method."

Comment: You need to decorate both of them. Also, what does it mean to POST to `api/Users`? If it means create a user then create a method that does that and name it `Post`

Comment: Now both of them cannot be invoked, and it seems always wants to map by the HTTP method ... and also told me the resource I request does not support Http Post method.

Comment: Did you remove the first two `MapHttpRoute` calls?

Comment: Yes, I remove all but the last one, and If I create PostUser method, then  "api/Users/SignIn"  maps to PostUser method, how can I make SignIn work.. ORZZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using attribute routing you need to differentiate between the two routes. Also once using routes it is all or nothing on the controller itself. You can't mix them with convention-based routes.

Review [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController {
    private Model1Container db = new Model1Container();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET api/Users
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers() {
        return db.UserSet;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SignIn")] //Matches POST api/Users/SignIn
    public IHttpActionResult SignIn(string account, string password) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SignUp")] //Matches POST api/Users/SignUp
    public IHttpActionResult SignUp([FromBody]User user) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")] //Matches GET api/Users/5
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id:int}")] //Matches PUT api/Users/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id,[FromBody]User user) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id:int}")] //Matches DELETE api/Users/5
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(int id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well,  at first the way you gave cannot work then I found out the problem is that the argument (**string** account, **string** password) cannot be passed in **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** format, is this one of the web api convention? So I changed to add both parameters to the URL or change the argument to type **User**, then everything works as expected with attribute routing, thanks.